# AppiumLibrary: Element Should Not Be Visible Keyword?

Tags: appium, robotframework

In `AppiumLibrary`, as of version 1.4.5, a very handy keyword called `Element Should Be Visible` has been introduced. But I am looking for the opposite version of that keyword too, which would be something like `Element Should Not Be Visible`. Since `AppiumLibrary` doesn't have that yet, is there any way we could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the possibility of expanding the library's python code, this shouldn't be very difficult. You basically just need to clone the `Element Should Be Visible` keyword definition and change the condition to do the opposite.

But, if that's not a possibility for you, perhaps you could use the keyword [Run Keyword And Expect Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error), in combination with the keyword you mentioned, `Element Should Be Visible`. Using this keyword on an element that isn't visible would throw an error, which in this particular case would be the desired outcome.

Still, that's a fishy workaround which will not help the readability of your test, and you should consider first looking into expanding the library itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Verv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8332700/verv) for the guidelines. I tried both approaches that he suggested, and both seem to be super easy. For future reference, I'm explaining both methods here.

**Method 1:**

Under `AppiumeLibrary/keywords` directory, there's a file called `_element.py`, which defines the `Element Should Be Visible` keyword. I was able to clone it to create the new keyword I was looking for.

Below is the code snippet that defines `Element Should Be Visible`

```
    def element_should_be_visible(self, locator, loglevel='INFO'):
        """Verifies that element identified with locator is visible.

        Key attributes for arbitrary elements are `id` and `name`. See
        `introduction` for details about locating elements.

        New in AppiumLibrary 1.4.5
        """
        if not self._element_find(locator, True, True).is_displayed():
            self.log_source(loglevel)
            raise AssertionError("Element '%s' should be visible "
                             "but did not" % locator)
```

Next to the above code snippet, you can add the following code snippet to define a new keyword `Element Should Not Be Visible`

```
    def element_should_not_be_visible(self, locator, loglevel='INFO'):
        """Verifies that element identified with locator is visible.

        Key attributes for arbitrary elements are `id` and `name`. See
        `introduction` for details about locating elements.

        New in AppiumLibrary 1.4.5
        """
        if self._element_find(locator, True, True).is_displayed():
            self.log_source(loglevel)
            raise AssertionError("Element '%s' should not be visible "
                                 "but did" % locator)
```

**Method 2**

If you don't want to expand the existing library, you could just use the combination of existing keywords as follows:

```
${isVisible}=  Run Keyword And Return Status   Element Should Be Visible   'someElementSelector'

Should Be Equal  ${isVisible}    ${FALSE}
```